# How to resolve the second promise if it required the first promise resolved result's element?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recurly

I have 2 function getAccountInfo() and getAdjustmentsInfo(accountInfo) they both return a new promise. The only different is that the second function needs the information returned from the first function.

I tried to declare these 2 function first, and call them one by one using then(). It worked but the problem is, the second fuction needs the the result from the first promise.

Not only that, the first promise returned an array, for example an array of 10 accounts infomation. But the second function only needs the attribute of the account information, for example account_code.

So I think I need to run the second function 10 time..? I am not very sure how to do that.

These are the functions, as you can see the second function needs account_code from the first accountInfo object:

```
function getAccountInfo() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getAccountCallbackFunc((errResponse, response) => {
            if (errResponse) {
                return reject(errResponse);
            }
            resolve(response);
        });
    });
}

function getAdjustmentsInfo(accountInfo) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getAdjustmentCallbackFunc(accountInfo[0].account_code, function (errResponse, response) {
            if (errResponse) {
                reject(errResponse);
            }
            if (response) {
                resolve(response);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This is the controller code to call the functions:

```
var accountInfo = {};
var adjustmentsInfo = {};

getAccountInfo()
    .then(response => {
        accountInfo = response.data.accounts.account;
        getAdjustmentsInfo(accountInfo)
    })
    .then(response => {
        adjustmentsInfo = response.data.adjustments;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I changed the second function into somthing like this, below is the code I changed to, so it can loop:

```
function getAdjustmentsInfo(accountInfo) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let result = {};
        for(account of accountInfo){
            getAdjustmentCallbackFunc(account.account_code, function (errResponse, response) {
                if (errResponse) {
                    reject(errResponse);
                }
                if (response) {
                    result += response;
                }
            });
        }
        console.log(result);
        resolve(result);

    });
}
```

So I run the getAccountInfo() function first and run the first then() to saved the account information to the external variable accountInfo. 
Next I run the second then() trying to pass the accountInfo to the second function, second function will loop and run the inner getAdjustmentCallbackFunc() multiple times to create and new result and resolve it. I dont't know why it is not working. Is that something I am missing? Please let me know.

Comment: try to change `getAdjustmentsInfo(accountInfo)` -> `return getAdjustmentsInfo(accountInfo)`

Comment: That loop is not going to work, you are calling `resolve()` immediately after the loop without waiting for the callbacks to have run. Keep your first version of `getAdjustmentsInfo`. If you really need to do some looping, call that `getAdjustmentsInfo` multiple times and learn about `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 1):

```
getAccountInfo()
.then(info => {
  return Promise.all(info.accounts.map(a => getAdjustmentsInfo(a)));
})
.then(adjustments => {
  // array of 10 adjustments
})
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answer my question, I tried these code, but it only return a list of promises....:     `getAccountInfo()
    .then(response => {
        accountInfo = response.data.accounts.account;
        return Promise.all([response.data.accounts.account.map(a => getAdjustmentsInfo(a.account_code))]);

    })
    .then(adjustments => {
        adjustmentsInfo = adjustments;
        console.log(accountInfo);
        console.log(adjustmentsInfo);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));`

Comment: @TianQin you have to remove the bracket in here `Promise.all([response` to `Promise.all(response` . The map will return an array, you dont need to wrap it in another one